# PDO Statements conversion for Drupal 9

Tags: php, database, drupal, drupal-9

I was wondering if anybody can help, i'm working on a module that requires a database query and will hopefully output the same data as an old PDO database query that I use to use outside of Drupal.

Within my module I am using the internal Drupal default connection method:

```
Database::setActiveConnection('DATABASE_NAME');
$db = Database::getConnection();
```

However what i'm having trouble with is finding out what the Drupal database query equivalents would be for the following PDO statements:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':test', $test);
$outputArr[0] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
$output = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/database-api/static-queries . Looks like it's just a wrapper around PDO anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Adyson, i'm getting 'PDO not found' whenever using it though...

Comment: Using what? The drupal functions, you mean? Please edit the question with exactly what you tried, and the full error message.

Comment: I assume you'll need to use \PDO since that class isn't in your module's namespace

Comment: @Don't Panic i'm generally in shock as to how just adding \ in front of PDO made all my statements work, thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome! Ha, I assumed that would be part of the problem, but I figured there would be more to it than that. I'm glad to hear it was an easy fix.